# Making a search bar in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, uisearchbardelegate

I made a search bar that looks like this

[image]

here's the full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class SearchInput extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<SearchInput> createState() => _SearchInputState();
    }
    
    class _SearchInputState extends State<SearchInput> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25, left: 25, right: 25),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: TextField(
                      cursorColor: Colors.grey,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        filled: true,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                          borderSide: BorderSide.none
                        ),
                        hintText: 'Search',
                        hintStyle: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          fontSize: 18
                        ),
                        prefixIcon: Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                          child: Image.asset('assets/icons/search.png'),
                          width: 18,
                        )
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only (left: 10),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
                    ),
                    child: Image.asset(
                    'assets/icons/filter.png'),
                    width: 25
                  ),
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

I don't know how to explain it specifically, Can i somehow code it when i press the search box leads to another new page for example this?

[image]

Or is there another way to make it happen? And please explain it step by step on how to do it if it's possible.

Comment: Can any one help me with that
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72123885/how-to-make-search-bar-to-search-a-song-and-play-it-flutter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `readOnly: true` and override `onTap` method to go next search screen

```
TextField(
   readOnly: true,  
   onTap: () {
      //Go to the next screen
   },
   cursorColor: Colors.grey,
)
```

Comment: I'll try it and will let you know if it works

Comment: Ofcourse, let me know what happend.

Comment: i marked it thank you for your help